# How to implement the "remember my password" for web users?

Tags: php

So that they don't need to type in their user/password next time.

I'm using jquery and PHP..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a long-lasting login cookie—the same way you do a normal login, but expiring later.

Comment: it is not a best way in php world, also to get this advice worked you should always have long-lived sessions.

Comment: @zerkms: I have no idea what you're saying.

Comment: I'm saying that "long-lasting login cookie" is not a good idea. There are **much** better solutions.